# Why is "duplicate" present twice as a flagging reason?

Tags: support, flags

When I flag a question (I don't yet have close privilege in this site), I see "duplicate" twice:

- right on the first form
- also under "needs improvement"

Is it intentional?

Also, I can't flag a question to be migrated to another site. According to my memories it was possible in the past.

[image]

[image]

As highlighted in the comments, this question has been already asked almost seven years ago ([New flagging dialog has a duplicate for duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196583)), but not received an official answer. So I hope to get it now.

Comment: Related: [New flagging dialog has a duplicate for duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196583) (received no official answer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two different duplicate flags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272987/two-different-duplicate-flags), notably, the "needs improvement" one opens the close vote menu so there is both a duplicate flag and a duplicate close vote (or something weird like that).

Comment: "Also, I can't flag a question to be migrated to another site. According to my memories it was possible in the past.".. Ermm.. flag → "needs improvement" (it's the new should be closed) → "A community-specific reason" → "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" → pick one.. Unfortunately all ellipses were removed. If you're using stylus or a userscript manager, there are a few workarounds in the Answers to [Please move the Flag Button back to the right side](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396585), which is my own post.

Comment: Is no one else laughing at the fact that a question on duplicate flags got flagged as a duplicate?